# .Net To DB2: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, .net, sql, db2-400

I have an asp site which has select query against IBM AS/400 database. If the application query just using one column name from the table, it returns the data however if i had more than one column name in the query , it throws `'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt'` error message. 
e.g.

```
SELECT ISDUI FROM PY.F55  <--returns data
or 
SELECT ISEMAL FROM PY.F55 <--returns data

SELECT ISDUI, ISEMAL FROM PY.F55 <--error out
```

Here is the .net code:

```
public int runDB(string cmd, string sub, ref DataSet ds, string type)
{
    try
    {
        if (iDB2DataAdapter1 == null)
        {
            iDB2DataAdapter1 = new iDB2DataAdapter("", new iDB2Connection(G_AS400conn));
            iDB2DataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
        }

        if (iDB2DataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            iDB2DataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();

        iDB2DataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText = @cmd;

        if (type == "S")
        {
            ds.Clear();
            rows = iDB2DataAdapter1.Fill(ds);
        }
        else
        {
            rows = iDB2DataAdapter1.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return rows;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //log error message
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a `System.AccessViolationException`?

Comment: You'll need to post the actual code that is executing that query. The query isn't causing that problem; something in your actual code is, and we can't help you without seeing it.

Comment: @KenWhite added .net code. #Serv yes it is.

Comment: Do me a favour and try the following in Visual Studio: `Options > Debugging > General > Uncheck Suppress JIT optimization on module load` and press f5 again. It should be the 7th option from the bottom (vs2013)

Comment: @Serv did that already before i posted this question. Still the issue persists. Thanks.

Comment: @sanjeev40084 Did you fix the issue? I am having the same issue. I cannot even return the data with one column.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the .NET Data Provider library you are using has the same production version as system you are connecting to.

We had the same issue with "AccessViolationException" exception reported, when trying to execute simple query to iSeries. Issue was resolved by upgrading IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll from V5R3 to the same version of target system: V5R4.